# Downgrading Angular module to AngularJS in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I have followed the instructions on how to downgrade an Angular module to AngularJS as I want to integrate an Angular app into an AngularJS app.
My Angular App contains a component with a html template containing some simple text:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
title = 'app';
}
```

In my app.module.ts I have the following:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
 declarations: [
  AppComponent
 ],
 imports: [
  BrowserModule
 ],
 providers: [],
 bootstrap: [],
 entryComponents: [
  AppComponent],
})

export class AppModule {
  public static ModuleName = 'app';
  constructor() {}
  ngDoBootstrap() {}
}
```

My main.ts contains the following:

```
import { enableProdMode, StaticProvider } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { downgradeModule } from '@angular/upgrade/static';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
 enableProdMode();
}

declare var angular: any;

const bootstrapFn = (extraProviders: StaticProvider[]) => {
 const platformRef = platformBrowserDynamic(extraProviders);
 return platformRef.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
};

 const downgradedModule = downgradeModule(bootstrapFn);

 angular.module('ui-components', [
   downgradedModule
 ]);
```

In my AngularJS part, I have a simple html in which I insert the name of my Angular component:

```
<div ng-controller="toastController as ctrl">
  <p>Hello world!</p>
</div>

<app-root></app-root>
```

The thing that I don't understand is how to communicate this module to my AngularJS app which is written in JavaScript. Just adding the downgradedModule to the dependencies of my AngularJS module does not work and leads to an error.
Could anyone help me on this and explain, please?

Comment: You need to load your Angular module's `main.ts` first

Comment: I have no idea where to load it?

Comment: Is my question explained badly? Can anyone help on this topic?

Comment: Need to know how you load app in your index